# Rails: is there a way to specify the controller for a route at runtime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Rails: is there a way to specify the controller for a route at runtime?

I'm developing a versioned API and would like routes to resolve to controllers in much the same way that bundler works, e.g. find the highest version controller <= the version asked for in the route...

Because there are an *infinite* number of minor versions between two indexes, I don't want staticly route with explicite routes. I'm hoping for a way to use a block to map incoming requests with the appropriate controller.

```
Given 
/app/controllers/api/v1.5.2/users_controller.rb
/app/controllers/api/v2.3.5/users_controller.rb

Route
GET /api/v1.5.2/user --> ~/v1.5/users_controller.rb
GET /api/v1.6.1/user --> ~/v1.5/users_controller.rb
GET /api/v1.7.7/user --> ~/v1.5/users_controller.rb
...
GET /api/v2.3/user --> ~/v2.3/users_controller.rb
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps a catch-all route would do the trick.... This is definitely a little hacky, but it's the first solution that comes to mind.

```
get 'api/*args' => 'api#show'

class ApiController < ApplicationController
  def show
    args = params[:args].split("/")
    version = args[0].classify
    resource = args[1].classify
    # not sure what params to pass in, so you'll have to figure that out
    "Api::#{version}::#{resource}".constantize.new([params]).show
  end
end
```

Can't say for sure whether or not this would work, but seems like it's a possibility.

Comment: No, I specifically don't want to create explicit routes at load time. I'm looking to route on the fly.